# Can i inject services into urlmappings?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Is it possible to inject a service in UrlMappings.groovy? Something like below...

**MyService.groovy**

```
class MyService {
    String foo() {
        return "test"
    }
}
```

**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {
    def myService

    static mappings = {
        "/${myService.foo()}"
    }
}
```

I am using Grails 3.0.11

Thank you

Comment: did you try `${applicationContext.myService.foo()}` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am getting a groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException error

Comment: When restarting the application, I got this error: ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]

Comment: Is there a reason you can't call a controller action method and delegate to the service from there?  Controllers are the intended place to handle the start of a request/response cycle.